# What's the value of $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\left[\frac{n^2+1}{n+1}\right]$

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Excuse my bad typing of mathematical symbols, I don't know how to type symbols. The $[ ]$ brackets are for the floor function where $[3.2]=3$ and $[2.9]=2$.

I have trouble calculating this limit, I know that floor function is mostly calculated by seperating it to two cases, where n is odd or even, but I can't go any further with this one. Any tips?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: If you let $y=\frac{n^2+1}{n+1}$, then it is $$\lim_{y\to\infty} \frac{\lfloor y\rfloor}y$$ which is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

For the term in the floor function:

$$\left[\frac{n^2+1}{n+1}\right]=\left[\frac{n^2-1+2}{n+1}\right]=n-1+\left[\frac{2}{n+1}\right]$$

For sufficiently large $n$, $\left[\dfrac{2}{n+1}\right]=0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\frac{n^2+1}{n+1} = \frac{n^2+n-n+1}{n+1}=n-\frac{n-1}{n+1} \implies \left[\frac{n^2+1}{n+1}\right]=n-1$$

Answer (score 1):

I would have approached the problem differently, abstaining from most math in favor of intuition.  Let $\lfloor A \rfloor$ denote the floor of $A$.

It seems immediate to me that as $A \to \infty$ the ratio 
$[E_1] \frac{\lfloor A\rfloor}{A}$ **must** go to $1$.

**Edit** per subsequent comment
$E_1$ holds, since $A-1 < \lfloor A \rfloor \leq A.$ 
Therefore, $\frac{A-1}{A} < \frac{\lfloor A\rfloor}{A} \leq \frac{A}{A} = 1.$

As $n \to \infty,$ the value 
$\frac{n^2 + 1}{n+1}$ is clearly going to $\infty.$

**Edit** per subsequent comment 
Therefore, based on $E_1$, as $n \to \infty$,
$\displaystyle \frac{\lfloor \frac{n^2 + 1}{n+1} \rfloor}{\frac{n^2 + 1}{n+1}}$ is clearly going to $1$.

Since the above fraction is going to $1$, as $n \to \infty$, the
**numerator** of the above fraction can be **replaced** by the **denominator.**

Once this **replacement** is made, the expression in the title of the OP's query exactly equals 1.  Note that the OP's query is concerned about evaluating the limit as $n \to \infty.$  By the above analysis, when $n \to \infty,$ the corresponding **replacement** is valid.

Comment: While this is a good initial line of reasoning, I don't think it makes a good answer. It is more suited for a comment. However if you'd like to flesh this out into a proper argument, observe that $\lfloor A \rfloor = A - \{A\}$ and $ 0 \leq \{A\} \leq 1$ to remove all doubt of any pathological counterexamples.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Did my editing make my reaction a good answer?

Comment: Yes. I posted my comment hoping you would edit because it is the most elegant solution here. If you could organize the post a little bit more that would lovely. Cheers

Comment: @NinadMunshi 2nd editing done.

Answer (score 1):

We can use squeeze theorem too

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n+1}{n^{2}+1}\left(\frac{n^{2}+1}{n+1}-1\right)}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n+1}{n^{2}+1}\left[\frac{n^{2}+1}{n+1}\right]}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n+1}{n^{2}+1}\frac{n^{2}+1}{n+1}}
$$

The leftmost and rightmost terms approach $1$ as $n$ goes to infinity, then the middle term does too